# How can I install 2 mysql instances in ubuntu using the generic binaries?

Tags: software-installation, mysql, tar, gzip

I want to install 2 mysql versions, one on the default port (3306) and the other on the 3308 port, on ubuntu 18.04 using the tar.gz file for generic binary installation. I would really appreciate if you could provide me with a step by step solution since I am new to Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do that by installing directly on the OS. A different approach might be using docker to run separate containers .

Understanding why you need such a setup can help me provide you with a more detailed answer.

As a starting points, i recommend looking into docker DevilBox.